# How to properly use instanceof and compareTo in the same line of code?

Tags: java, instanceof, compareto

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Employee emp; 
    if (o instanceof Faculty) { //if it is faculty
        emp = (Faculty)o; //cast this employee to an object
    } else if (o instanceof Staff) { // if it is staff
        emp = (Staff)o; //cast this employee to an object
    }
    int difference = this.salary().compareTo(emp.salary());
}
```

What I'm trying to do right now is check if the employee is part of the faculty or staff (children of its parent class employee) and properly implement the compareTo to check the salary.

This is the pay/salary method

```
public Faculty(String n, String i, String o, double s) {
    super(n, i, o); //add a o which is office from its parent Employee
    salary = s;
}

public double pay() { 
    return salary;
}
```

I'm just kind of stuck at this point.

The pay/salary differs between the two of them. Staff gets paid on a rate * hours and faculty gets a fixed pay of 1500.

Comment: Are you trying to compare only by salary?

Comment: Why are you using `compareTo(Object o)` and not `compareTo(Employee o)` by having your class implement `Comparable<Employee>`? Having your class be comparable to any object instead of limiting what it can be compared to isn't really good design.

Comment: There are several parents that exist in my program at the moment, including a superclass "parent". The interface I created compareTo is public interface Comparable {
 int compareTo(Object o);
}

Comment: Wait, do I understand this right and you created your own Comparable interface instead of using the existing one `java.lang.Comparable<T>`?  Why?

Comment: @lealceldeiro Yeah, that's it pretty much. The goal is to just list the individual persons info and compare their salary. It should return the difference.

Comment: @lealceldeiro I understand the logic behind what I'm doing, I just don't know how to implement it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving out some (arguable, or not) design aspects, etc... inside `compareTo` you just need to check if the argument `o` is instance of `Employee`. Whether it is specifically instance of `Faculty` or `Staff` doesn't really matter because the method `salary` executed will correspond to it's specific type (`Faculty` or `Staff`) thanks to *polymorphism*.

So, it would go like this:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Employee ? this.salary().compareTo(((Employee)o).salary()) : -1;
    // replace -1 for any value you'd like to return if o is not instance of Employee
}
```